# Jersey POST Method is receiving null values as parameters

Tags: java, json, rest, post, jersey

I am developing RESTful services with Jersey and it works great with GET methods. However I can't make it work with POST methods and JSON or text parameters. These is what I did:

```
@Path("/method/")
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public ResponseObject method(@Context Request request, @PathParam("ob1") Object obj1, @PathParam("obj2") String obj2) {
...
}
```

I am only getting null values for all params. I have tried to use just a string as parameter and it doesn't work either ... I am trying to access these methods from IOS and maybe that's one of the problems. However I have been sniffing my LAN and I can see the correct parameters in the packet body ... is this correct??

I have sent from XCode different body contents as:

```
obj1={"id1": "value1", "id2" : "value2"}&obj2=xxxx
```

and:

```
{"id1": "value1", "id2" : "value2"},xxxx
```

while I have been playing with @QueryParam and @PathParam without results...always null...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A path parameter is a portion of the request URL matching a particular pattern. As such, there are character limitations on what can be specified as a path param - in particular any special characters need to be URL encoded. This applies the same across any kind of request (*GET*, *POST*, *PUT*, *DELETE*).

As a general rule, you should restrict your path parameters to simple values like identifiers, or resource endpoints - more complex data should be passed to the REST service via request parameters or the request body itself. Here's a mixed approach that passes an entity identifier as a path parameter, and the entity data in the request body:

```
@Path("/contacts/{id}")
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateContact(@PathParam final String contactId, Contact contact) {
}
```

In the above example, the *contactId* is obtained as a path parameter and the contact is serialized automatically from the request body.

What I described above are ***general*** rules. Now as to the specifics of your case, one thing I notice in your code is that you don't actually define any path parameters. Remember that they have to be defined as part of your `@Path` annotation, before being consumed in your REST method:

```
@Path("/method/{obj1}/{obj2}")
public ResponseObject method(@Context Request request, @PathParam("obj1") Object obj1, @PathParam("obj2") String obj2) {
}
```

With the above changes your parameters should no longer show up as being null, assuming you have properly encoded the URL on the client side.

---

*** EDIT ***

Based on your comment, I see you need to become more familiar with the JAX-RS specification and the various parameter types. I recommend reading through the [RESTEasy JAX-RS Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html). It has some vendor specific implementation details but all in all is an excellent guide to JAX-RS.

---

#### @PathParam

***Purpose***: Used to inject a portion of the request URL into a variable. Note that URL parameters are *not* considered part of the URL.

***Example***: Given the URL *http://services.example.com/contacts/20578*, I can define:

```
@Path("/contacts/{id}")
```

From which I can inject a `@PathParam("id")`.

```
public Response getContact(@PathParam("id") final String identifier);
```

This works for *any* kind of HTTP request (*GET*, *POST*, *PUT*, *DELETE*).

---

#### @QueryParam

***Purpose***: Used to inject a portion of the query string or form encoded data into a variable. The query string is that portion of your URL after the `?`. Form encoded data are the URL encoded name/value pair data passed in the body of an HTTP request, when the request type is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*. Typically, query parameters are passed as part of the URL string for GET requests, and in the request body for POST requests.

Example: Given the URL http://services.example.com/contacts?group=Business, I can inject a `@QueryParam("group")`

```
public Response getContactsInGroup(@QueryParam("group") final String groupName);
```

It's atypical to use query parameters with a POST request, but it is possible if the request type is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*:

```
@POST
@Path("/contacts")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response createContact(@QueryParam("contact") final Contact contactData, @QueryParam("metadata") final String metaData);
```

These are just high level examples, please read through the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_PathParam) I linked to get a better example of how each parameter type works, and when to use which one.

Comment: Hi Perception, I didn't put the parameters in the Path param because I use a POST method so I thought there was no need to put it (it is not present at the URL).  If I put the parameters in the path param I didn't receive anything to the server... I thought using PathParam and QueryParam would be used only to know how to pass the parameters to the post request... what is jersey expecting then in the request body?? Thanks so much

Comment: @Kasas - that was a pretty broad followup question, I linked some documentation in my answer which should be helpful in getting more information.

Comment: Thanks @Perception, I have been reading it and it made me clear some aspects...one of the most important is that you can only treat one request parameter in the request body...so it was imposible to treat two parameters in the way i was doing it. You must use multipart/mixed to do it or make another complex type (that's my solution). However the problem with null parameters is not completely solved... tomorrow i'll find the solution and i'll post it here ;)... I hope! I think it is a problem with the way IOS format the JSON String...

Comment: After putting all in the same parameter everything worked fine. Thanks for the help @Perception. My method now consumes a paramenter like {"obj1":{"id1": "value1", "id2" : "value2"},"obj2":"xxxx"} and everything is fine :).

Answer (score 6):

I just started developing webservice in java and had a same problem with POST data.
I got very simple solution to read the POST data using [@FormParam](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_FormParam), Actually i was using the [@QueryParam](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_QueryParam) to read POST data, I think its only for reading the QueryString data using GET method

A very nice documentation given here. Having read this article, most of my confusions were cleared.
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html

Tip: Just make sure you are using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" mime type while using @FormParam

Answer (score 1):

I'd post this as a comment to the accepted answer, but I'm just shy of being able to do that.

In addition to the excellent advice above, I would add that, at least in version 2.0.x, Jersey does not pull `@FormParam`  from the query string.  Instead, it expects it to be included as a name-value pair in the request body.

For example, instead of `POST http://localhost/app?name=Joe`, you would send
 `POST http://localhost/app`
with the body:

```
name=Joe
```

Answer (score -3):

Assume we have a `tenant` object which has `id` and `name` attributes and REST resource is exposed via  `@POST` and `@PATH("/xyz/tenants")`.

Body example in JSON:

```
{"id":"001","name":"myname"}
```

Body example in XML:

```
<tenant><id>001</id><name>myname</name></tenant>
```