# Pass and receive JSON object from Jersey Resftul webservice from android

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, rest

Scenario : Pass username and password in a json object to restful webservice and get a json object in return. Yeah, I know, Its simple but I can't get it work.

I have been trying to this from several days. So far, I have tried this:

My restful webservice code

```
@POST
    @Path("/testJson")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject testJson(JSONObject inputJsonObj) throws Exception {

        JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject();

        if(inputJsonObj != null){

        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("JSON object = " + inputJsonObj.toString());
        System.out.println("=================================");

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("JSON is NULL");

        }

        myjson.put("success", "1");

        System.out.println(myjson.toString());

//        return "string returned";
        return myjson;
    }
```

And inside my android acivity, the code is

```
// POST request to <service>/SaveVehicle
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(myURL);
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("user-agent", "Yoda");


        try {
            // Build JSON string
            // JSONStringer vehicle = new JSONStringer().object()
            // .key("getItInputTO").object().key("zipCode").value("90505")
            // .key("financingOption").value("B").key("make")
            // .value("Scion").key("baseAmountFinanced").value("12000")
            // .key("modelYear").value("2010").key("trimCode")
            // .value("6221").key("totalMSRP").value("15000")
            // .key("aprRate").value("").endObject().endObject();

            JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject();
            myjson.put("1", "first");
            myjson.put("2", "second");

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(myjson.toString());
            entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json; charset=utf-8"));

            request.setEntity(entity);

            // Send request to WCF service
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
//          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, localContext);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            resCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (resCode == 200) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                HttpEntity entity2 = (HttpEntity) response.getEntity().getContent();
                String text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);

                if(text!=null){

                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(text);

                    lblMsg.setText("Successful!");
                }

                // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                // InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                //
                //
                // String line = "";
                // StringBuffer returnFromServer = new StringBuffer();
                //
                // while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // returnFromServer.append(line);
                // }
                // // Toast what we got from server
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // returnFromServer.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //
                // if (entity != null) {
                // entity.consumeContent();
                // }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

The commented sections show previous tries.

**Output that I get on server console**

```
=================================
JSON object = {}
=================================
{"success":"1"}
```

My server side receiver json object is not getting populated i don't know why.

Note:

1. I have INTERNET and many other permissions in my android manifest.
2. My webservice is up and running.
3. I have all the required jars i.e. jersey, json etc
4. I am using Tomcat 7 for restful webservice

I would highly appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like this is possibly an issue on the server side.  What is the expected result?  Have you tested the server response outside of your app?

Comment: The expected result is that I get the passed json object on the server side.

Here is what I am passing
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject();
            myjson.put("1", "first");
            myjson.put("2", "second");

Comment: Is there no one to answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as yours.
I don't know why, but the temporary solution i am using is creating a class to handle those parameters.

That means using Jackson to convert Json Object <=> "Your Class"

See this tutorial for more information:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

===================================

And I just found this topic, it may be more useful than the upper solution:
[Jersey POST Method is receiving null values as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357041/jersey-post-method-is-receiving-null-values-as-parameters)